# How to suppress Jquery Validation submitHandler when cancel button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, struts2, jquery-validate, submit

Here I have a problem with Jquery Validation plugin and Struts2.

I have 3 buttons like below in my form.

```
<td><s:submit type="button" value="Save" theme="simple" cssClass="valid" /></td>
<td><s:submit type="button" value="Cancel" theme="simple" action="cancel" cssClass="cancel"/></td>
<td><s:submit type="button" value="Submit" theme="simple" cssClass="valid"/></td>
```

When the form is submitted, the validations will be done using jquery validation. After the form is successfully submitted, I want user confirmation to submit the form ?

So I used submitHandler of Jquery Validate function.
But When i click cancel also this submitHandler is getting executed. I dont want anything happened when cancel button is clicked. Here is the JavaScript part.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#MyForm").validate({
    //Some validation rules
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        //this runs when the form validated successfully
        //My code after submitting the form 
            alert("Hello");
        } //End of Submit Handler
    });

});
```

I know it will be a simple answer.Though Please help me find it people

Comment: why struts2 is tagged to this question?

Comment: Because I'm implementing this application in struts2 framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem is that your `form` contains three `submit` buttons.  Even though each one has a different `value`, the plugin will trigger the same on each one.

1)  Change the cancel button into a `type="reset"`.  The plugin will ignore this type of input (however, the HTML will clear the form data).

http://jsfiddle.net/hnyd2/

OR

2)  Move the cancel button *outside* of the `form`.  The layout will be different but you can place the button more precisely using CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/hnyd2/1/

OR

3)  Leave it inside the `form`, but block the default behavior of the `submit` button using jQuery's `preventDefault()`.   You must put an `id` on the button so you can target it properly.

```
$('#cancel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // anything else to do on click
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hnyd2/3/

Comment: Dude.. Thanks for your reply.
1) If i change the type to type="reset" then struts2 framework throws error.
2)If i move the cancel button outside of the form then the action class associated with it is not working.. I mean the action is getting called..

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @Andy, you could try to block the default function of the button using jQuery.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Sparky. Let me try youe 3rd option.. i hope it works.. !!